# Inherit text-shadow with units relative to a child element without selecting all children

Tags: css

I want to create a text shadow for an element, and I want all the children of that element to **inherit** that shadow. The issue is that relative units (i.e.: em, ex, ch) of the inherited text-shadow are relative to the calculated `font-size` of the element it was created on (i.e.: the parent element).

Also, I understand that

```
parent, parent * {
    text-shadow: 1em 2em 3em currentColor;
}
```

will work fine, but I'd prefer to avoid the `*` selector. I don't want to select every single child element, but more importantly, I don't want to mess with specificity.

(How) Is this possible?

Comment: Something like this? [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/T74L7/1/)

Comment: Nope. The shadow is inherited, but the units are not relative to the _child_'s `font-size`. http://jsfiddle.net/T74L7/2

Comment: What about `text-shadow: 5rem 0rem 0rem #999;`

Comment: That won't work either. The idea is that I would set a text-shadow on the parent, and its children would have a shadow that grows or shrinks as the font-size grows or shrinks.

Comment: I don't think you can inherit text-shadow in the way you want (`text-shadow: inherit` keeps the settings of the parent). You could select only direct children with `parent, parent > *`, but I know that still uses the universal selector. There's probably js solutions. . .

Answer (score 0):

(I am unable to comment thanks to restriction of 50 poitns for comments, hence the question in answer tab & a possible solution which I will update based on answers:P)

So @uber5001, 
Question 1: For clarity, are you selecting all child elements or not? First line you did say, you want to select all the child elements. And at the end of your question you said, you don't want to select all children of your parent element. Sorry I couldn't understand what you meant by that.

In the jsfiddle you provided in your comments, adding `text-shadow: 5em 0em 0em #999;` to `#parent p:first-child` gives the desired effect.
http://jsfiddle.net/ssaCw/1/

I believe you are trying to acheive the same thing?
Please let me in the details so I can update my answer.

**EDIT:**
Since you want the rules to apply to every single child element, this is what I am able to think of:
http://jsfiddle.net/ssaCw/2/

Use `#parent p:nth-child(n) {
    text-shadow: 5em 0em 0em #999;
}`

Hope it helps :) Is there something else as a constraint as well?

Comment: I know I _can_ achieve the desired effect, but I want to do so without extra CSS for every font change, and without the `*` selector, so I don't have to worry about specificity when nesting these kinds of css rules. Ultimately, yes, I will need to select all the children to use `inherit`. I'm doing this because I want the convenience that `inherit` provides. However, it seems impossible to do so in this case of changing font-sizes.